# Dbeaver Connecting to Hive - SQLException: Method not supported

Tags: hive, dbeaver

```
I'm getting this error when trying to run a select after connecting to Hive.
```

Is this a bad jar file?

```
org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.JDBCException: SQL Error: Method not supported
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(JDBCConnectionImpl.java:170)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(JDBCConnectionImpl.java:1)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.DBUtils.createStatement(DBUtils.java:985)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.DBUtils.prepareStatement(DBUtils.java:963)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.runtime.sql.SQLQueryJob.executeSingleQuery(SQLQueryJob.java:313)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.runtime.sql.SQLQueryJob.extractData(SQLQueryJob.java:633)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.SQLEditor$QueryResultsProvider.readData(SQLEditor.java:1169)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetDataPumpJob.run(ResultSetDataPumpJob.java:132)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.runtime.AbstractJob.run(AbstractJob.java:91)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Method not supported
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.createStatement(HiveConnection.java:229)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCConnectionImpl.createStatement(JDBCConnectionImpl.java:350)
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(JDBCConnectionImpl.java:138)
... 9 more
```

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. Did you manage to get to the bottom of it? Also, what drivers are you using, and what Hive-Hadoop distro are you connecting to?

Answer (score 1):

There is a calls in hive jdbc jar called org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveResultSetMetaData . This class contains a method isWritable which is not supported by hive yet. This is the reason why you get the error "Method not supported".

Take the source code of this class and update the above method. Then generate the class and replaced it in the jar. This worked for me.